# get buffer array from CImage AtlImage

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc, atl

I'm trying to get the byte buffer of an `AtlImage`. Type is `CImage`
This code will just scale an image loaded from path `szFilePath`
Here it is :

```
int iNewWidth = 60;
int iNewHeight = 60;

CImage image;
image.Load(szFilePath);

CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
CDC *pMDC = new CDC;
pMDC->CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

CBitmap *pb = new CBitmap;
pb->CreateCompatibleBitmap(screenDC, iNewWidth, iNewHeight);

CBitmap *pob = pMDC->SelectObject(pb);
image.StretchBlt(pMDC->m_hDC, 0, 0, iNewWidth, iNewHeight, 0, 0, image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
pMDC->SelectObject(pob);

CImage new_image;
new_image.Attach((HBITMAP)(*pb));

int bytesnbr = abs(new_image.GetPitch()) * new_image.GetHeight();
mSize = bytesnbr;
mBuffer = new BYTE[bytesnbr];
DWORD dwValue = pob->GetBitmapBits(bytesnbr, mBuffer);

new_image.Detach();
ReleaseDC(screenDC);
```

I'm getting an exception `isDibSection()`
I would like to get the buffer to encode it in base64.
Maybe is there an other way... Anyway I need to scale the image.
Thanks for help

Comment: What do you mean by "_I'm getting an exception `isDibSection()`_"? I don't see a function by that name mentioned in your code. Where does the exception occur?

Comment: This exception is from atlimage.h when I call GetPitch

Comment: Why not using the Save method supplying an IStream created with CreateStreamOnHGlobal

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [`GetBitmapBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144850.aspx) on images that are DIB sections. It works *only* with device-dependent bitmaps (DDBs). Presumably, MFC saved you from this bug with an assertion that verifies internally that the `CImage` object is not a DIB section.

What you should be using is [`GetDIBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879.aspx), which is what you should be using *anyway*, since `GetBitmapBits` became obsolete circa mid-1990s with the introduction of 32-bit Windows.

More generally, your code looks like it was written by someone translating from Java. You don't need to `new` up all those objects. Just create them on the stack using automatic allocation.

Comment: How to use GetDIBits with CImage??